# How can I get the row value before editing in js-GRID

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, jsgrid

In js-GRID I want during editing a row(editTemplate) to get the initial value of this row before the new one. The specific js-GRID column is a text field.

This i my code but so far but in my alert I get nothing.

```
editTemplate: function() {

                    //Access the current text field
                    var variableGroupEditResult = jsGrid.fields.text.prototype.editTemplate.call(this);

                    //alert(variableGroupEditResult.val());

                    return variableGroupEditResult;
                    },
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the code:

```
onItemUpdating: function(args) { previousValue = args.previousValue;
}
```

And apart from that I passed the `previousValue` to my `editTemplate` and it is done.